# How to append and remove all element under div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a form for product sale. admin can add fields for multiple product's click on add button using jquery and can remove by clicking on remove button. I'm trying to append this using div id but this doesn't work.
here is my html part.

```
<div class="row" id="dsf">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <select name="p_name" class="form-control" id="p_name">
            <option value="">-Select Product-</option>
            @foreach($products as $product)
                <option value="{{$product->product_id}}">{{$product->name}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="text" name="p_code" id="p_code" class="form-control" readonly="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="text" name="unit_pctn" id="unit_pctn" class="form-control" readonly="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="text" name="u_price" id="u_price" class="form-control" readonly="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <input type="text" name="ctn" id="ctn" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <input type="text" name="pcs" id ="pcs" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="text" name="t_amt" id="t_amt" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my jquery part.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#addrow").click(function(){
        $("#dsf").append();
    });
});
```

Comment: What are you trying to append? Your current code appends nothing.

Comment: The append function need a parameter

Comment: You need to specify the *content* (or in this case, the element in question) that you want to insert by a *parameter* you declare between the parenthesis of `.append()`. **see:** https://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: i want to append all element under id="dsf"

Comment: Try use te toggle function https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_toggle.asp

Comment: And where do you want to append that on? On the body? On a table? On another div?

Comment: try this

 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#addrow").click(function(){
            var content = $("#dsf").html();
            $('#addrow').append(content);
        });
    });

Comment: @WouterBouwman to `#dsf` - this part of the question seems clear.

Comment: i want append on the same div -Wouter Bouwman

Answer (score 1):

if you want to append data after div then use this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#addrow").click(function(){
            var content = $("#dsf").html();
            $('#addrow').append(content);
        });
    });
```

this is demo code for test

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#addrow").click(function(){
            var content = $("#dsf").html();
            $('#addrow').append(content);
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" id="dsf">

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="text" name="p_code" id="p_code" class="form-control" readonly="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="text" name="unit_pctn" id="unit_pctn" class="form-control" readonly="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="text" name="u_price" id="u_price" class="form-control" readonly="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <input type="text" name="ctn" id="ctn" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <input type="text" name="pcs" id ="pcs" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="text" name="t_amt" id="t_amt" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="addrow">Click</div>
```

or you can append after **addrow**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#addrow").click(function(){
            var content = $("#dsf").html();
            $( content ).insertBefore( "#addrow" );
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" id="dsf">

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="text" name="p_code" id="p_code" class="form-control" readonly="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="text" name="unit_pctn" id="unit_pctn" class="form-control" readonly="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="text" name="u_price" id="u_price" class="form-control" readonly="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <input type="text" name="ctn" id="ctn" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <input type="text" name="pcs" id ="pcs" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="text" name="t_amt" id="t_amt" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="addrow">Click</div>
```